# Spark Scala code does not compile when used with a encoder + by name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is a simplified version of my code that is failing to compile:

```
object CompileFail {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Encoder, SparkSession }

  case class Foo(x: Int)

  def run(spark: SparkSession): Int => Int = {
    import spark.implicits._
    add(bar(encode[Foo]))
  }

  def bar(f: => Int): Int = 0

  def encode[A : Encoder]: Int = 0

  def add(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
}
```

It is failing with following non sensical message:

```
[error] Error while emitting CompileFail.scala
[error] value $u
[error] one error found
[error] Compilation failed
```

I am on `Scala 2.12.15` and `Spark 3.1.2` (but it fails on older Spark versions too).

Interesting to note:

1. If I change `add(a)(b)` to `add(a, b)` it compiles
2. If I change `bar(f: => Int)` to `bar(f: Int)` it compiles
3. If I change `add(bar(encode[Foo]))` to `add(bar(encode[String]))` it compiles

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I strongly think it has something to do with the implicit's the Encoder library brings in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, it's a bug in scala resolution. Only doing this simple change works.

```
object CompileFail {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Encoder, SparkSession }

  case class Foo(x: Int)

  def run(spark: SparkSession): Int => Int = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val i = encode[Foo]
    add(bar(i))
  }

  def bar(f: => Int): Int = 0

  def encode[A : Encoder]: Int = 0

  def add(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
}
```

It looks like it has conflicts with the implicit resolution and the lambda conversion of the function.